# SDL hangs when using SDL_SetVideoMode with SDL_OPENGL as parameter

Tags: opengl, sdl

As the title says, my application hangs while running SDL_SetVideoMode, but only when i specify that I want to use OpenGL. Otherwise it initiates without any problem.

**Edit:
When waiting ~50 seconds, it manages to initiate.**

**Edit 2:
Driver update solved it.**

Code looks something like:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 600, 24, SDL_OPENGL);
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Using Visual Studio 2010 and SDL/OpenGL libraries are linked as the should be (as far as i know).

Comment: That looks OK to me, are you sure it is not a drivers problem? Do you know for sure it crashes inside that function? And if so, did you use a debugger to see why/where it crashes?

Comment: It never crashes, just hangs. However, it seems that if I wait for ~50 sec, it manages to initialize. Will edit post.

Comment: So I've just run into this exact same issue on Ubuntu Precise. Using a debugger I was able to track the problem down to a call to GLXMakeCurrent(); the application simply hangs at that function, sometimes for as long as 20-30 seconds, then continues as normal. As far as I know, my drivers are all up-to-date. Has anyone else had this issue in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Driver update solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

That looks OK to me, are you sure it is not a drivers problem? Do you know for sure it crashes inside that function? And if so, did you use a debugger to see why/where it crashes?